# Iterating checkboxes in order in groupbox

Tags: vb.net, forms, checkbox, groupbox

I am currently studying VB.NET

I have question about reading checkbox(or textbox or combobox) or read in group box

for example I have this windows form

[image]

And I have code like

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For Each cb As CheckBox In GroupBox1.Controls
        MsgBox(cb.Name)
    Next
End Sub
```

I was expecting reading checkbox 1 -> 2 -> 3-> 4 -> 5

However, it sometimes read 5->4->3->2->1 or 3->4->2->1->5

I was thinking "Tabindex" might affect read order, so I changed TabIndex for each checkbox. However, it didn't affect to  change order of reading checkbox

is there any way to control order of reading checkbox(or anything) in groupbox ?

thanks

**----- UPDATE------**

I got idea for Linq.
I think that will be the easiest way to solve this issue.
I will update when I got right answer
thanks**

Comment: instead of iterating control/object references, you could use a `List(of String)` which holds their name,  They should be in ZOrder, but that changes when you fiddle with the form, so if you have code depending on the order, use a List.

Comment: @Plutonix Thanks for your helping. This is example code. If form has more than 10 number of checkbox for options, then searching name can be complicated to implement.(like using nest for loop and using select case to find right checkbox) I am studying how to simplify code based on iterating :(

Comment: how is it complicated? *you* can create any set of names you need in whatever format.  Its no harder using a string collection to iterate than a controls collection

Comment: @Plutonix  I was thinking control 25-30 checkbox. And, I have arraylist<Boolean> to make sure i need to check or uncheck each checkbox in the groupbox. Can you provide simple example that I can study about it ? I am not sure how to use "List(of String)" to check or uncheck each checkbox in the groupbox. I know that I can set name of each checkbox  in the groupbox. However, I don't really know way to apply List(of String) to solve this issue :(

Comment: If you now have *2* bits of information related to each other (and the control) - the name and state of the checkboxes.  I'd use a class to keep the info together.  Do you know about them?

Comment: Set the Tag object of each control. Then loop through the controls. Does it really matter the order, what are you doing anyways?

Answer (score 0):

```
for i = to 1 to numberofcheckboxes
 if Directcast("checkbox" & i, Checkbox).Checked = True Then
    'do something
 end if
next
```

Of course you can change the method .Checked to what suits you best.